# Texture Packer sprite red message error

Tags: javascript, textures, sprite, game-engine, texturepacker

In TexturePacker, I'm getting a weird red frame:

[image]

[image]

I can't quite read what it says, but I'm assuming it's protection for their software. I purchased the full version (pro + physics package) tonight and properly entered the key I received.

Any idea how to get rid of that?

---

Edit: someone else had this issue [here](https://twitter.com/hamcha/status/252001722883522560), and it seems to indeed be a "Please purchase license to use" message. There was no resolve though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry for the inconvenience.

Please open TexturePacker's preferences from the menu. Press "Reset all".
This should fix the issue.

In case it does not work don't hesitate to contact me via mail:
support at codeandweb.com

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I was using Texture Packer on the command line when I received this error message:

> You are using some advanced features which will cause some sprites to be colored red in the sprite sheet

I fixed it by reactivating my license key with the following command:

```sh
TexturePacker --activate-license <KEY>
```